# Remover parte da string

Tags: jquery, string

Preciso modificar uma *string* com jQuery. Suponha que eu tenha uma variável endereço:

```
var endereço = "Rua emanuel meira martins 85 cic curitiba...";
```

A ideia é remover todas as letras depois da posição 15 e adicionar três pontos (...).

Como posso realizar esta operação?

Answer (score 5):

Pode fazer assim:

```
var endereço = 'Rua emanuel meira martins 85 cic curitiba'.slice(0, 15) + '...';
```

Que neste caso dá: `Rua emanuel mei...`

O método nativo [.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) aceita dois parametros, o ponto de partida e o ponto final do trecho do original que vai ser usado. Isto é JavaScript puro. Não precisa de jQuery aqui.

Comment: valeu !________

Comment: @user14579 se a resposta solucionou o seu problema pode marcar como aceite. Reparei que tem outras perguntas onde pode fazer o mesmo.

Comment: @Zuul no problem. Corrigi também :)